# How to disable that when I l click the down arrow in PowerPoint for mac, the focus moved to the search box

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-powerpoint

I cannot use the `down arrow` key on my Mac in Power Point. Instead of going to the next line in the text area, it moves the focus to the search bar.

What should I do?

I know that Steve Jobes wanted us to be addicted to use the TrackPad, but I preffer to use the keyboard to navigate between lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if you have changed default behaviour?
In my Powerpoint 16.20 for Mac, the arrow keys behave normal. The short cut for search bar is CMD+F.

Can you verify, that no shortcut in system settings / keyboard / shortcuts interfers?

Also some third party Apps like Clipboard tools, Window resizers etc sometimes remap shortcuts.

Comment: You right it was on my Mac. I opened settings, click !https://pasteboard.co/I2NyzwE.png Restore Defaults, and now it's working.